# How to preset parameters that are not time related into time series for Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How do you preset time-independent properties for devices that record time-series data in Apache IoTDB? Such as attributes like serial number, warning water level, jurisdiction area etc. I think these data would not be changed and the type of data would also not be changed. I want to remark them to the corresponding time series data. Anyone has any idea on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time series is automatically created by default in Apache IoTDB. If your "preset" data type will not be changed, you can directly `insert` your data into the time series.